# What is wrong with this object being capable of telling how many of its properties are not null/whitespace/empty?

Tags: c#, constructor, system.reflection

I am trying to figure out why the following code throws a StackOverflowException (I am finally posting a StackoverflowException in SO!).

Debugging seems to point out that the p.GetValue(this) is generating further calls.

What is actually triggering the infinite call chain ? Is it because p.GetValue(this) ultimately returns an instance of the current object, and thus acts as if constructing a new instance (and every object that constructs itself within its construction will lead to Stackoverflow exceptions) ?

My intent with the following code is to have an object being capable of telling how many of its properties have null/space/empty values.

```
public class A
{
    public string S1 { get; set; }
    public string S2 { get; set; }

    public int NonInitializedFields
    {
        get
        {
            int nonNullFields = 0;

            var properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
            foreach (var p in properties)
            {
                var value = p.GetValue(this);
                if (value == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.ToString()))
                    nonNullFields++;
            }

            return nonNullFields;
        }
    }
}

//the following throws a StackOverflowException (the construction line itself)
A a1 = new A1{ S1 = "aaa"};
Console.WriteLine(a1.NonInitializedFields);
```

P.S. My idea originally involves only simple string properties, nothing else, so whatever problems may arise with this approach with other types are not relevant.

Comment: This is not the scope of the question - I am only interested in simple string properties (and every other scenario and its peculiarities and eventual problems are not relevant)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a *property*, which, when you execute the "get" accessor, finds all the *properties* and fetches their value. So it executes itself, recursively.

If you only want string properties, you should check the property type *before* fetching the value:

```
var properties = GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string));
```

At that point, as your `NonInitializedFields` property doesn't have a return type of `string`, it won't be executed.

Personally I would make this a method call rather than a property anyway, mind you. That would also fix the issue, as the method wouldn't find itself when looking for properties.

I would also rename it, as:

- A property isn't necessarily backed by a field
- A field could be explicitly initialized as `null` or a reference to a string containing only whitespace

A method called `GetNonWhitespaceStringPropertyCount()` would be more accurate, IMO. You can also make the whole implementation a LINQ query:

```
return GetType().GetProperties()
                .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(string))
                .Select(p => p.GetValue(this))
                .Count(v => !string.IsNullOrWhitespace((string) v));
```

Note that I've fixed the next issue in your code - you're meant to be counting *non-null/empty* values, but you're actually counting null/empty ones.

Comment: I do not relate to the string type issue because the object is mine and I am sure it will always be (really :-)

Comment: So for this to work actually... simply making it a method will do it right - the problem is since it is a property and the property is "computed" at construction time ? (If it is a method, it will execute only once, at the method call, and not recursively - am I right ?)

Comment: @Veverke: Yes, changing this to a method would remove the problem - but I would still make the code explicitly look for string properties. Then you don't need to call `ToString()` etc, you can just use: `string value = (string) p.GetValue(this);`. In fact, you could do the whole thing with a LINQ query - I'll edit to show how.

Comment: I appreciate your suggestions about making it more specific - and I agree with them - this was solely for a very punctual need so there is no point in investing much. Please state making it a function will remove the problem, since the code being part of a property is what makes it create the infinite call chain. Thanks Jon.

Comment: @Veverke: I've made it clearer that that would fix the issue, but I've still left the rest of the answer - bear in mind this is primarily for future readers, not just you. You may choose to ignore good practices for this code (despite the result being merely four lines long - look at the end of the answer) - but I hope future readers won't.

Comment: yup, I noticed I am counting the opposite =]